# WebView in fragment doesnt load any webpage, kotlin, android

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I am trying to load webpages in fragments to use in my new app, the problem is the code runs but for every website it shows me a white screen, no crashing or error messages. I am also trying to do this in Kotlinwhich might not be a good idea...But currently still have the time to port to java
AndroidManiferst.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.braun.testingwebview">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestingWebView">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TestingWebView.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

fragment_first.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="213dp"
        android:layout_height="108dp"
        android:text="Test"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/WebView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

FirstFragment.kt

```
package com.braun.testingwebview

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_first.*

class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val myWebView: WebView = WebView1
        myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView,
                url: String
            ): Boolean {
                view.loadUrl(url)
                return true
            }
        }

        myWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com")
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        myWebView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
        myWebView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        myWebView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: What is WebView1 here? Add full code of fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Put WebView part of code in onViewCreated rather than of onCreateView, in onCreateView just inflate the fragment'x xml layout and return the view.
Action on fragment container should be made in onViewCreated after view created by onCreateView function.

So your modified code will be:

```
override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    }

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
val myWebView: WebView = view.findViewById(R.id.WebView1)
        myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView,
                url: String
            ): Boolean {
                view.loadUrl(url)
                return true
            }
        }

    myWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com")
    myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    myWebView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
    myWebView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    myWebView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
```

}

Comment: I have tried that but still, get a white screen

Comment: Try to load content rather than URL and then check it's working or not?

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate what sort of content?

Comment: Check this https://www.javatpoint.com/android-webview-example

Comment: Unfortunately no luck, still nothing loads

Comment: Might be it's loading button due to design complexity it is not properly visible into design. So do one thing put background color into Webview and check it's there or not.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
 class LogoutFragment : Fragment() {


    private var _binding: FragmentLogoutBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = FragmentLogoutBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        return root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val myWebView: WebView = view.findViewById(R.id.WebView)
        myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView,
                url: String
            ): Boolean {
                view.loadUrl(url)
                return true


            }


        }
        val webSetting:WebSettings = myWebView.settings
        webSetting.javaScriptEnabled = true
        myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

        myWebView.canGoBack()
        myWebView.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { v , keyCode, event ->
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK

                && event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                && myWebView.canGoBack()){
                myWebView.goBack()
                return@OnKeyListener true
            }
            false
        })


        myWebView.loadUrl("https://youtube.com")
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        myWebView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
        myWebView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        myWebView.settings.useWideViewPort = true


    }

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer with more details about what you changed, why and how this should fix the question.

Answer (score 0):

I probably had the same issue, ending in a white screen. Figured out I can just call loadurl on my WebView, without using a WebViewClient and it works. Not sure if it's good practice, but atleast it did display some content

```
class WebViewFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentWebViewBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentWebViewBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val myWebView = binding.wvWebViewScreen

        myWebView.loadUrl(url)
    }
}
```

web_view.xml is just a simple webview wrapped by Relative Layout.